# Receiving Email with any E-mail Address

Tags: email, spoof

I am aware about spoofing and it is possible to send an E-mail using any address you wanted.

My question is: Is it possible to receive an E-mail using any address you want?

Example: I received an E-mail from iamhimATprivatedomainDOTcom, that has been spoofed. Is it possible to reply to the address and the person who is trying to spoof me, received the E-mail even though privatedomainDOTcom is a private email server?

Comment: To receive all e-mails sent (for example) to my address, you'd have to hack into my e-mail account. Without it, it would still be possible to receive e-mails sent to my address, but only through network that you control. If you want to receive any e-mail sent to any arbitrary address, I'm afraid you're out of luck ;)

Comment: So is it safe to say that, if I don't have access to the network, I would not be able to receive any email with the domain address? Even if I replied to the wrong IP origin of the spoofed E-mail?

Comment: To be more to the case I am dealing with: I received an E-mail from a friend and I was unaware of the different IP origin of the E-mail. The E-mail was from the company he worked with official domain name. I replied to him with quick reply, and he replied back with the exact same E-mail address. We exchanged a few E-mail like this and I had no suspicion at all. Much later on, I met with him, and he said it was not him who replied. I checked and I just realized his e-mail address is 1 letter off, but the domain is intact and exact. Is his company's E-mail server hacked?